# basic authentication, when field user admits :

Tags: http, basic-authentication

Is it possible to use basic authentication when the username and password fields do not make any restrictions on the type of characters to be used?

Example, could exist a user with the following values:

- username: `iamThe:User`
- password: `My@Secure:Password`

To convert to basic authentication:

- concat username:password =  `iamThe:User:My@Secure:Password`
- convert to base64 and add to header `Authorization: Basic aWFtVGhlOlVzZXI6TXlAU2VjdXJlOlBhc3N3b3Jk`

How do I get back the username and password from the following field `aWFtVGhlOlVzZXI6TXlAU2VjdXJlOlBhc3N3b3Jk`?  is there a solution for this?

Comment: When you say get back, do you mean on the server? That is you have control of the sever. If this is the case then you could concat the username and password and use a different delimter that cant be used by the username/password. ie.   something like `username|||password`

Comment: The username and password fields do not have character restrictions. There are already users created on the server. I am asking if I can use the basic auth standard in this case or is it a restriction that the character : is not allowed in the username

Comment: Think about what you are saying! If `ANY` username or password already contains a `:` then it is impossible to deconstruct using a `:` as a delimiter. Therefore you have to choose something the database can never get from a user, or at least VERY improbable to get from a user

Comment: I wanted to adapt as much as possible to the standard, I find it hard to believe that this situation is not contemplated. I can always do my own implementation, for example use base64username-base64password